# Windbg analyze SQLDump

Tags: sql, clr

We have problem at a SQL-server. It happens when a SQL server agent job runs and the job calls a CLR.

Can anyone help me to see from the dump file what is wrong?

```
`0:000> kc 100
 Call Site
 KERNELBASE!RaiseException
 sqlservr!CDmpDump::Dump
 sqlservr!SQLDumperLibraryInvoke
 sqlservr!CImageHelper::DoMiniDump
 sqlservr!stackTrace
 sqlservr!stackTraceCallBack
 sqlservr!ex_handle_except
 kernel32!UnhandledExceptionFilter
 ntdll! ?? ::FNODOBFM::string
 ntdll!_C_specific_handler
 ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
 ntdll!RtlDispatchException
 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
 msxml6!Base::freeRentalObjects
 msxml6!Base::StackExitNormal
 msxml6!ModelInit::~ModelInit
 msxml6!SAXReader::parse
 MSO
 0x0
 0x0
 0x0`
```

I think it's difficult to know how to handle the information.

Thanks in advance!